# EF : custom logic to know which object to include/load

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, code-first

I have the following classes:

```
public class A
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public ICollection<B> AllB { get; set; } = new List<B>();

    public B Current { get; set; }

    // other properties
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid AId { get; set; }

    public A A { get; set; }

    // other properties
}

// in the DBContext
public DbSet<A> AllA { get; set; }

public IQueryable<A> AWithAllB
{
    get
    {
        return AllA.Include(c => c.AllB);
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<A>().ToTable("A");
    builder.Entity<A>().HasKey(h => h.Id);

    builder.Entity<B>().ToTable("B");
    builder.Entity<B>().HasKey(h => h.Id);
    builder.Entity<B>().HasOne(h => h.A).WithMany().HasForeignKey(r => r.AId);
}
```

Basically, there are many B for one A.

What I struggle with is the property Current from A.
I want this property to be populated but with a custom logic to find which B to load.

In my case, it will be the instance of B with the highest Id that I want as Current. This logic will change in the future.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you "violate" separation of concerns in some way. EF is "mapping" framework for simply getting data from database. So putting there your "business" logic will complicate things as you have noticed already. It will be much simpler and in some cases even effectively if you just retreive your data from database and then "map" collections and `Current` property based on your logic

Comment: Well, I agree, but in this case, most of the time, I really don't want to load All the B objects just to retrieve one of them.

Comment: " I really don't want to load All the B objects just to retrieve one of them" use lazy loading.

Comment: @AnilKumar I don't see how lazy loading changes anything here. He says that I should load them all then filter out the one I want. Whether I lazy load or not, I will load them all anyway (for this instance of A).

Comment: I'm with @Fabio on this one. Better to put this logic outside of your EF model. Add a `Current` property but do not do anything with it in your mapping. Have it be populated by whatever process (service,controller,etc) is doing the retrieval.

Comment: If you really wanted to add it in a lower layer you could create a new database view and map to that view instead of the table. Then you add Current and logic to the database view. Downside is the model would be restricted to select (view) only.

Comment: _I really don't want to load All the B objects just to retrieve one of them_. That was exactly what i tried to explain. 1. Load data of class `A` without collection of `B`. 2. Load one object of `B` based on your logic (for example `tableOfB.Where(b => b.A.Id = loadedA.Id)`). 3. Combine them in `A.Current = loadedB;`